# Function that abbreviates a number (e.g. 1202 => 1.2K)

Tags: javascript

Like Twitter and Instagram and others I wanted to display numbers like 1.2K and 3.8M etc. My function works well enough but I would appreciate any input you may have.

```
function abbrNum (num) {
    if(typeof num !== 'number') {
        throw new TypeError('Expected a number');
    }

    var shortNumber;
    var exponent;
    var suffixes = ['K', 'M', 'B', 'T'];
    var size = (num + '').length;

    exponent = size % 3 === 0 ? size - 3 : size - (size % 3);

    if(num < 1000) {
        return num;
    } else {
        shortNumber = Math.round(10 * (num / Math.pow(10, exponent))) / 10;
    }

    if(exponent < 6) {
        shortNumber += suffixes[0];
    } else if(exponent < 9) {
        shortNumber += suffixes[1];
    } else if(exponent < 12) {
        shortNumber += suffixes[2];
    } else if(exponent < 16) {
        shortNumber += suffixes[3];
    }

    return shortNumber;
}
```

Update: This code (updated according to feedback) is available on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/short-number).

Comment: [Be careful of long- vs. short-scale billions...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales)

Comment: I probably could not help rewriting `size % 3 === 0 ? size - 3 : size - (size % 3)` as `(size - 1) - (size  - 1) % 3`.

Comment: @CarstenS I would prefer `Math.floor((size-1)/3)`

Answer (score 18):

converting to string just to get the length won't work if there is a decimal or it's large enough that the string conversion uses scientific notation.

```
var size = floor(log(num)/log(10))+1;
```

This will give the place of the highest significant digit (1 to 9 results in 1, 10 to 99 results in 2, 100 to 999 results in 3, etc...)

Comment: Can I ask why you're dividing log(num) by log(10)? Isn't log(10) always 1? In which case you could just do `floor(log(num))+1`

Comment: @AndyF I wasn't sure if the base of `log()` was 10 and the division will always make sure that I get the base I want.

Comment: `Math.log()` gives you a natural logarithm, so `log(10)` is roughly 2.3. @ratchetfreak is doing the right thing, since log(a)/log(b) = logarithm base b of a.

Comment: Beware the troubles of floating point math, or why it is generally a good idea to write unit tests: `Math.floor(Math.log(1000)/Math.log(10))+1)` already gives me 3 instead of 4 with Chrome. While there is no built-in method to compute the integer logarithm (that I know of) it's an easy to write method and will actually work correctly.

Answer (score 11):

Your function does not entirely work as you would expect for larger numbers.

I did some testing of your code in my browser's console and I came across this:

```
> abbrNum(1234567890123)
"1.2T"
> abbrNum(1234567890123456)
"1.2T"
```

You should add some support for when a number is too big. Perhaps you could throw an exception that the number is out of bounds that your function will work in.

---

This little construct:

```
    if(exponent < 6) {
        shortNumber += suffixes[0];
    } else if(exponent < 9) {
        shortNumber += suffixes[1];
    } else if(exponent < 12) {
        shortNumber += suffixes[2];
    } else if(exponent < 16) {
        shortNumber += suffixes[3];
    }

    return shortNumber;
}
```

Is not very flexible. What if you decide to add more suffixes? As you add more and more `if else`s, this construct just gets more and more ugly.

I recommend creating an object where the values are the number to check the exponent against, and the keys are the suffixes to add.

That would look like this:

```
var suffixes = {
    "K": 6,
    "M": 9,
    ...
}
```

Then, to check which suffix to add, you simply loop through this construct:

```
for(var suffix in suffixes) {
    if(exponent < suffixes[suffix]) {
        shortNumber += suffix;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify your solution for adding the suffix? As it's written it will just add every suffix for numbers less than one million for example.

Comment: @cfj Ah, you are right. I have changed the code; it should work now.

Comment: Yup, it works now. Just make sure you delete the old array.

Answer (score 7):

It does currently not work for negative numbers – also a user of the API may just assume this – which could easily be solved by using the absolute value of the input number:

```
if(Math.abs(num) < 1000) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks pretty clear for me, A few things:

1 - If is less than 1k, avoid the other operations, so after the type-check, add that validation.

2 - For more expressibility, considerate using a dictionary or avoid array of suffix.

```
  function abbreviationNumber (num) {
        if(typeof num !== 'number') {
            throw new TypeError('Expected a number');
        }

        if(num < 1000) {
            return num;
        }

        var shortNumber;
        var exponent;
        var size = (num + '').length;

        exponent = size % 3 === 0 ? size - 3 : size - (size % 3);    
        shortNumber = Math.round(10 * (num / Math.pow(10, exponent))) / 10;

        if (exponent < 6) {
            shortNumber += 'K';
        } else if(exponent < 9) {
            shortNumber += 'M';
        } else if(exponent < 12) {
            shortNumber += 'B';
        } else if(exponent < 16) {
            shortNumber += 'T';
        }

        return shortNumber;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

None of the given answers - or the original code for that - is actually *correct*.

Here is a minimal test harness to test the heart of the whole problem: Figuring out the right exponent for a given number:

```
function test(input, expected, func) {
    var result = func(input);
    if (result !== expected) {
        console.log("Invalid result for " + input + " expected: " + expected + " actual: " + result);
    }
    return result === expected;
}

function testHarness(funcName, func) {
    console.log("Testing " + funcName);
    var successful = true;
    for (var i = 1, number = 1; i <= 50; i++, number *= 10) {
        successful &= test(number, i, func);
        if (!successful) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (successful) {
        console.log(funcName + " passed test correctly.")
    } else {
        console.log(funcName + " did NOT pass test!")
    }
    return successful;
}
```

The original answer fails at 1e21 because that is when Chrome decides to use scientific notation for floats, while ratchet freak's solution already gives the wrong result for `1000`.

For reference here is the obvious implementation of an `ilog10` algorithm that is as correct as possible (to the best of my knowledge) considering the inherent imprecision of floating point (you just cannot represent 1e55 or so as a IEEE-754 double so that's where this becomes problematic):

```
function ilog10(val) {
    var i = 1;
    var number = 10;
    while (val >= number) {
        i += 1;
        number *= 10;
    }
    return i;
}
```

What also seems to work - but I'd definitely want to write more test cases to be sure is to use `Math.floor(Math.log10(val)) + 1`. It passes the basic unit test in any case.